# Como remover margem branca de um Carousel (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, carousel

Eu criei um carousel no meu site através do código do Bootstrap, e estou querende que ele ocupe toda a largura da tela (100vw) e quase toda a altura (90vh); portanto, eu pus no container width: 100vw e height: 90vh, mas quando eu abro o site o carousel fica com algo similar à uma margem branca (eu tentei utilizar o margin:0px e o padding:0px, mas não adiantou), e isso faz com que ele ultrapasse o limite da tela (fica com uma barra de rolagem vertical), além de que o atributo height sequer funciona. Como eu poderia consertar isso?

Meu código:
  HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="topo">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/1.png" alt="1" class="carousel_img">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/2.png" alt="2" class="carousel_img">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/3.png" alt="3" class="carousel_img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0px;
}

body {
height: 400vh;
}

#topo {
width: 100vw;
height: 90vh;
}

.carousel_img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "margem branca" é gerada pela regra css padrão da class "container-fluid", que aplica padding left e right de tamanho 15px para o elemento que contenha essa classe.

Para remover essa margem, você pode sobrescrever essa regra da classe container-fluid adicionando o css abaixo:

```
.container-fluid { padding: 0 !important; }
```